# Swift Error in inheritance init class

Tags: ios, swift, class, inheritance

I have an error when un want init my B object.

My error is : `Use of 'self' in property access 'name' before super.init initializes self`

```
class A {
    let name = "myName";
}

class B:A {
    let point: ObjectWithName;

    init() {
        self.point = ObjectWithName(name); // error here
        super.init();
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing `name` which is declared in the superclass. But the superclass has not been initialized yet (it will after `super.init()`).

So it's a logic problem.

### Solution #1

You can declare `point` as `lazy`, this way it will be executed **after** the whole `init` process has been completed, unless you call it before.

```
struct ObjectWithName {
    let name: String
}

class A {
    let name = "myName";
}

class B: A {
    lazy var point: ObjectWithName = { ObjectWithName(name:self.name) }()
}
```

### Solution #2

Inside `A` you can define `name` as `static`

```
class A {
    static let name = "myName";
}

class B:A {
    let point: ObjectWithName;

    override init() {
        self.point = ObjectWithName(name: B.name)
        super.init();
    }
}
```